# How to re-initialize a USB drive after it had been disabled due to overcurrent?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I occasionally get a `device descriptor read/64, error -71` on a permanently connected USB drive. It's powered by a single port, so I figure the reason for that is overcurrent and I should think about feeding more power to it, but in the meantime I just want it to recover without having to physically re-plug it.

The drive is completely gone from the system, as far as I can tell, it's not even listed by `lsusb`.

So is there a software way to make the system detect and re-initialize it? I know the exact USB port it's connected to, if this helps.